# Recover cyclotomic integer with bounded coefficients from its known associate

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, algorithms, computational-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Recall that two cyclotomic integers are called [associated](https://planetmath.org/associates) if their ratio is a unit in the corresponding ring of cyclotomic integers.

We will view cyclotomic integers as polynomials (of degree $<\varphi(n)$) with integer coefficients modulo the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$.

> Q: Given a cyclotomic integer $p(x)$ modulo $\Phi_n(x)$, how to find all its associated cyclotomic integers $q(x)$ that have bounded coefficients?

Particularly interesting cases:

- $q(x)$ has coefficients from $\{0,1\}$;
- $q(x)$ has nonnegative coefficients summing to a given integer $s$.

---

*Remark.* A naive approach would be generating all polynomials $r(x)$ with bounded integer coefficients of degree at most $\varphi(n)-1$ (there is a finite number of them) and checking if $r(x)/p(x)$ is a unit, however it's hardly feasible for large $n$. I hope it's possible to somehow exploit the structure of units to recover the required polynomials $q(x)$ more efficiently.

Comment: As a side comment, the units are not easy to find/check: see this question.  Also, you could try a simplified search by multiplying for the cyclotomic units which are quite explicit: https://planetmath.org/IndexOfTheGroupOfCyclotomicUnitsInTheFullUnitGroup. One could hope to find a bound on which cyclotomic units could possibly contribute (maybe some coefficient diverges when you multiply many times?). But then there is the problem of non-cyclotomic units, which implies a finite search from any candidate polynomial.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to bound the unit, say u, and compute all the u(x)p(x)? Using that the units form a f.g. group under multiplication will give a smaller search space.

Comment: @AndreaMarino: As for checking for a unit, isn't it enough to check that the norm equals 1?

Comment: @FelipeVoloch: The question here - how exactly to bound suitable units $u(x)$?

Comment: You are right: checking a given thing is unit is easy, finding them all it's hard

Comment: "As a side comment, the units are not easy to find/check: see this question." What question?

Comment: "Call two cyclotomic integers equivalent if their ratio is a unit in the corresponding ring of cyclotomic integers." This is the same as saying the two cyclotomic integers are *associates*, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thank you for the hint - I've updated terminology.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying by powers of the units and check bounded coefficients? According to sage the coefficients of large powers of units are large.

Comment: @joro: This is essentially what Felipe suggested above. However, I need a quantitative/guaranteed way to restrict the set of suitable candidate units.

Comment: If $q=up$, then $u=q/p$ in the cyclotomic field. The height satisfies $H(ab)\le H(a)H(b), H(1/a)=H(a)$ (Lang, Fund. Dioph Geom 3.1), so $H(u) \le H(q)H(1/p)=H(q)H(p)$.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch: Thanks for the explicit bounds! I'll try your idea although I'm not yet convinced that the search space of units, which depends on the factor $H(p)$ here, would be much smaller (if not larger) than that of $q$.