# Compute 01-vectors in the orbit of a given vector wrt a finitely-generated abelian subgroup of SL(n,ℤ)

Tags: matrices, combinatorial-optimization, abelian-groups, 0-1-matrices, integer-matrices

Given a vector $v\in\mathbb Z^n$ and pairwise commutative matrices $M_1,\dotsc,M_k\in \operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb Z)$, how to compute all 01-vectors in the orbit of $v$ with respect to multiplication by elements of $\langle M_1,\dotsc,M_k\rangle$?

This question is inspired by a particular approach to the previous one: [Recover cyclotomic integer with bounded coefficients from its known associate](https://mathoverflow.net/q/429289).